# Schedule actions in background in Android

Tags: java, android, background

I need to program an Android device to be able to make an action (send http request) at a specific time, maybe in background, I need to schedule this action, like a clock alarm.

For example, I may need to schedule this http request at 8:00AM the next day, and to be able to process the response.

I don't know which strategy to use, I have researched but I don't find native Android Objects suituable for this situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the doc from Google. [Guide to background processing](https://developer.android.com/guide/background)